# Single Test with Multiple Subjects

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

**How can I make dynamic test cases?**

Those searches input is not hard-coded, it's generated by function (- it will do a whole crawl of all the web pages and find every apps and save it with {name: xxxx, link:, xxxx})

For each search, there should be a individual group of tests from 'step 1' to 'step 4'

I changed to Mocha, but Mocha seems to compile test cases before I process the searches input

Using before, or add a 'step 0 - process searches', doesn't seem to work.

```
var searches = [];

describe('search', function() {
    before(function(browser) {
        searches = populateSearch(browser);
    });
    it('step 0 - process search': function(browser) {
        searches = populateSearch();
    });
    searches.forEach( search => {
        it('step 1 - launch url': function(browser) {
        });
        it('step 2 - click search box': function(browser) {
        });
        it('step 3 - type in search': function(browser) {
        });
        it('step 4 - search found in search lists': function(broswer) {
            assert.equal(search.name, 'xxx')
            assert.equal(search.link, 'xxx')
        });
    });
});
```

Right now, I'm think two options

a) Using browser.globals.searches to populate from a previous test, and it shows populated in tests cases it(string, () => {}). But it still doesn't work, since browser.globals.searches at compile time is empty, so no test cases generated?
Is there any way that mocha can first run one test to populate to the globals variable, and then compile the actual test, so that the tests are dynamically created?

b) Using node to make dynamic and run, one problem with this is I cannot add nested describe in the suite, how do I add nested describe?

```
var Mocha = require('mocha');
var Test = Mocha.Test;
var Suite = Mocha.Suite;

var mocha = new Mocha();
var suite = Suite.create(mocha.suite, 'Search Box');

suite.addTest(new Test('I\'m a dynamic test', function () {
    console.log("haha");
}));
```

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to use async: --delay and run()

In nightwatch.json

```
"test_runner" : {
    "type" : "mocha",
    "options" : {
        "ui" : "bdd",
        "reporter" : "list",
        "delay" : true
    }
}
```

In search.js

```
"use strict";
var helpers_1 = require('../util/helpers');
var utils_1 = require('../util/utils');
var subjects_1 = require('../util/subjects');

var nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

var client = nightwatch.initClient({
    silent : true
});

var browser = client.api();

function test() {
    describe('Search', function () {
        browser
            .url(browser.launch_url)
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 3000, function () {
                helpers_1.getToCheckTiles(browser);
            });
    Object.Keys(browser.globals.toCheckTiles).forEach(function (type) {
        browser.globals.toCheckTiles[type].forEach(function (tile) {
            it('step 1 - launch url': function(browser) {
            });
            it('step 2 - click search box': function(browser) {
            });
            it('step 3 - type in search': function(browser) {
            });
            it('step 4 - search found in search lists': function(browser) {
                assert.equal(search.name, 'xxx')
                assert.equal(search.link, 'xxx')
            });
        });
    });
    run();
});

setTimeout(test, 10000);
```

The program just halts for whichever timeout I typed, and exit

Comment: In nightwatch, I cannot use --delay, and use run, the tests just halt; Please see my update

Comment: Ah, yes. I've reopened.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with my config or test